# Empty animation makes Transform Inspector yellow, model without animation has keyframes

Tags: animation

I have 2 models in my blender scene.

One model has animation, the other one doesn't.

When I click the one who doesn't have an animation, it shows keyframes in the Action Editor.
Also, when I scrub through the animation, the Transform Inspector flashes its color from Green to Yellow.

[image]

My 2 questions would be

1. Why does the model without an animation show keyframes?
2. What causes the Yellow flashes in the Transform Inspector?

I have uploaded a [video here](https://youtu.be/h4omZKVlrVs).
And this is the blend file:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your still armature has been keyframed. It stays still because all the poses are the same all along the timeline, orange lines between the yellow dots mean that there are no change between all these poses.

In the *Transform* panel, green value means the armature is animated but is not keyframed at the selected frame, yellow means it is keyframed at the selected frame.

If you zoom in you'll see that the keyframes have been scaled and do not match with the timeline anymore, thus the sometimes green color on the *Transform* panel, when you're on a frame where there are no keyframe:

[image]

If you select and move the keyframes you can easily make them match to the timeline, and you'll see that your *Transform* panel will be yellow all along the scrub:

[image]